# Disable a user's login without disabling the account

Tags: users, login, password, authorization

Let's say I create a user named "bogus" using the `adduser` command. How can I make sure this user will NOT be a viable login option, without disabling the account. In short, I want the account to be accessible via `su - bogus`, but I do not want it to be accessible via a regular login prompt.

Searching around, it seems I need to disable that user's password, but doing `passwd -d bogus` didn't help. In fact, it made things worse, because I could now login to bogus without even typing a password.

Is there a way to disable regular logins for a given a account?

*Note: Just to be clear, I know how to remove a user from the menu options of graphical login screens such as gdm, but these methods simply hide the account without actually disabling login. I'm looking for a way to disable regular login completely, text-mode included.*

Comment: Your `-d` is the flag to delete the password. That is different from disabling it (refereed to as locking, see Chad's answer).

Comment: You probably want to completely disable them: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7690/how-do-i-completely-disable-an-account  Also see this Ask Ubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/282806/how-to-enable-or-disable-a-user

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
passwd -l user
```

is what you want.

That will lock the user account.  But you'll still be able to

```
su - user
```

but you'll have to `su - user` as root.

Alternatively, you can accomplish the same thing by prepending a `!` to the user's password in `/etc/shadow` (this is all `passwd -l` does behind the scenes). And `passwd -u` will undo this.

Comment: By using the `passwd -l` option you should be aware that the user could login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key).

Comment: Please see my [answer below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129477/67687) on a recommended solution on how to avoid this.

Comment: This does not work on ubuntu 16.04. It will change the expire date and not allow su - user anymore.

Comment: Is this same as the `--disabled-password` option given to `adduser`? Does creating a user without `--disabled-password` and then running `passwd -l` on that user achieve the same result as running `adduser` with `--disabled-password` in the first place?

Comment: @haridsv on Alpine (likely the same on other distros, untested) if I use `--disabled-password` and then ran `passwd -l user` I get the error `passwd: password for user is already locked`. I assume they're the same yes.

Answer (score 51):

The man page of `passwd(1)` says about `passwd -l`:

> Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still
>   be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH
>   key). To disable the account, administrators should use usermod
>   --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2,
>   1970).

So

```
usermod --expiredate 1 [LOGIN]
```

seems to me like the right way to disable an account a user should not be able to use anymore (e.g. because he left the company).

Comment: On my CentOs 6.3, `passwd -l` does block `ssh` connection for a user, and `usermod --expiredate 1` doesn't!

Comment: On my CentOS 7.4, `passwd -l` no longer blocks `ssh` connections for a user, and `usermod --expiredate 1 user` does block. Per `man passwd` you can also use `chage -E 0 user` to block a user. After applying `usermod` or `chage` I am able to `sudo su user`

Comment: `usermod --expiredate 0 [LOGIN]` also works, it sets the expire date to Jan 1 1970 whereas a 1 sets this to Jan 2 1970.

Comment: "The value 0 should not be used as it is interpreted as either an account with no expiration, or as an expiration on Jan 1, 1970." -- shadow(5)

Answer (score 33):

There are two methods to prevent a user from being able to login:

1. you can lock the user by editing `/etc/passwd`
2. by directly issuing the `passwd` command with the `-l` switch

In the second case the user can login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key).

**Method #1**

1. Find where is nologin: /bin/nologin or /bin/sbin/nologin
2. Open a terminal and login as root
3. Type `vi /etc/passwd`

Now you are in `passwd` file press <kbd>Ins</kbd> to edit the file.

Change the below line with the `nologin` option (`/bin/bash` means the user is able to login).

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

to this. `nologin` means the user is unable to login.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/nologin
```

(or with /bin/sbin/nologin)

4. Close the vi <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:wq</kbd>

**Method #2**

To lock user: `passwd -l username`

To unlock user: `passwd -u username`

Comment: On an Ubuntu 14.04 system, I found `/usr/sbin/nologin` instead of `/bin/nologin`.

Comment: Tip: use `which nologin` to determine the correct path for your system

Comment: In modern distros you no longer can succeed with `su - user` if user's shell set to `nologin` as you will be bounced back with `This account is currently not available.`. You can still succeed for accounts locked with `passwd -l` though.

Answer (score 9):

Its quite easy task you simply have to make some changes in `/etc/passwd` file.

Simply you have to change the shell which is generally by default `/bin/bash` I.e you can login using this shell change it to `/bin/nologin` or `/bin/false`. It is advisable to change it to `/bin/nologin` because `/bin/false` is outdated.

Answer (score 4):

Set `/bin/false` as a shell in `/etc/passwd`

Comment: When one sets the shell to `/bin/false`, one prevents using su to act as that user.  Additionally, using `/bin/false` produces no error nor other hint of what just went wrong -- in cases where one does want to prevent even su from being used to get a shell as that user, the shell should be changed to `/sbin/nologin` which does produce an error.

Comment: No, the `su` is still possible for users with `/bin/false` shells in `passwd` - just use the option `--shell`: `su - --shell /bin/sh bogus`.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/nologin` has the same effect as `/bin/false`, but also shows a useful informational message.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to start with a fresh user account:

```bsh
sudo adduser --no-create-home --disabled-password --disabled-login <uname>
```

---

With `usermod --expiredate 1 <uname>` I had the problem that this account cannot be used for nothing anymore (e.g. for samba logins). My use-case was that I want to disable all functionality for ssh, ordinary, ... logins but still use it as a Samba user.

Answer (score 0):

When we lock the user using the `passwd  -l user` command, "`!!`" are indicated in the `/etc/shadow` file. But we can still able to switch to a user shell from the root account, but not able to switch to user account by other normal users login shell.

We can also disable account by providing `/bin/nologin` or `/bin/false` in to `/etc/passwd` file. So user may not able to login in.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command

```
usermod -s /sbin/nologin username
```

Comment: this way `su username` fails with `Cannot execute /sbin/nologin: No such file or directory`