# What is "-l" option do to the passwd command?

Tags: password

I have seen people use `passwd -l "$USERNAME"` ,

But the linux man page does not explain what the `-l` option is for. What does it do ?

Comment: Really? My copy of the man page for `passwd` *does* document `-l`.

Comment: mine doesn't. And I can't find it online either.

Comment: First Google hit for "passwd man page" documents it.

Comment: But can you explain what the above does ? Does it just set the username as blank?

Comment: Now if I knew what it did, I wouldn't have asked the question. If I had asked "How do I Disable a user's login without disabling the account ?" then it would be a duplicate. I was trying to figure out what someone is trying to do with the -l option.

Comment: Uh... They're trying to "lock the password of the named account", exactly as documented. No?? It sounds like maybe what you want to know is how the `-l` option is *implemented* internally. But that's not what you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this by issuing the `passwd` command at the CLI

```
-l, --lock                    lock the password of the named account
```

It locks the account so that `root` has to unlock the account before this person can log-in and use the account again.

**EDIT** As it was indicated this is a duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19333/disable-a-users-login-without-disabling-the-account)

Answer (score 2):

The `-l` switch for `passwd` locks the user account by changing the password to a value which matches no possible encrypted value. Only root has access to `passwd -l`.

Note that `passwd -l` does not keep the user from gaining access through other means such as authentication tokens (like SSH keys).

To lock access to a user account:

```
passwd -l  username
```

To unlock an account again:

```
passwd -u username
```

Answer (score 1):

It is documented:

```
$ man passwd
...
       -l, --lock
           Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a
           password by changing it to a value which matches no possible
           encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the password).
...
shadow-utils 4.1.5.1              07/26/2013                         PASSWD(1)
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55115/2594